# How do I extract integer values from PHD using pyodbc?

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to a Honeywell PHD server using Python 3.x and extract data. I am connecting with this syntax:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
connstring = str('Driver={PHD Server x64}; Server=xxx')
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstring, autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = "SELECT value FROM phd_data where tagno = '36012' \
        and start_timestamp = 'NOW-::1'"
df = pd.read_sql_query(query,conn)
struct.unpack('f',df.loc[0,'VALUE'][:4])[0]
```

This works fine for the tag number 36012 (and many others) as their data type is Float. The VALUE column in the table PHD_DATA returns a byte string with 4096 bytes. Most of the bytes are \x00 but there is some regular text mixed in that seems to relate to python, see below:

```
b'\xd4]\xf0CD\x00 \x00W\x00r\x00i\x00t\x00e\x00 \x00D\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00 \x00T\x00a\x00b\x00l\x00e\x00\x00\x00t\x00i\x00o\x00n\x00 \x00T\x00a\x00b\x00l\x00e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00.\x00.\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x014\x00\xb1\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xc1\x91\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00j\x00s\x00o\x00n\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01du\xb1\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x0b1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00n\x00o\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00l\x00i\x00z\x00e\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\xf7\xe9\xb1\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01D(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00t\x00a\x00b\x00l\x00e\x00_\x00s\x00c\x00h\x00e\x00m\x00a\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\xfe\x1b\xae\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01T\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00X\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00_\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00t\x00_\x00_\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe9\xbd{\xfe\x8ah\xd7\x01\x9a\xe8\xd1\xe6\x18\xb0\xd7\x01]d\xb0\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01]d\xb0\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00_\x00_\x00P\x00Y\x00C\x00A\x00~\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00_\x00p\x00y\x00c\x00a\x00c\x00h\x00e\x00_\x00_\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xaa\xa7u\xfe\x8ah\xd7\x01g\x04\xcf\xe6\x18\xb0\xd7\x01\'~\x05\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\'~\x05\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00_\x00_\x00P\x00Y\x00C\x00A\x00~\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00_\x00p\x00y\x00c\x00a\x00c\x00h\x00e\x00_\x00_\x00\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\xa7\x10\x9d\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xdf\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00f\x00e\x00a\x00t\x00h\x00e\x00r\x00_\x00f\x00o\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x14"{\xfe\x8ah\xd7\x01\xbe\x9a\xd1\xe6\x18\xb0\xd7\x01zH\xac\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01zH\xac\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00f\x00o\x00r\x00m\x00a\x00t\x00s\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01D\x0b\xad\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xf7\x1f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00g\x00b\x00q\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01.\x80\xad\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01=\x87\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\x00t\x00m\x00l\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\'\x97{\xfe\x8ah\xd7\x01\x9e\xc1\xd1\xe6\x18\xb0\xd7\x01\xf7\xe9\xb1\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xf7\xe9\xb1\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00j\x00s\x00o\x00n\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\xd6^\xb2\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01n\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00o\x00r\x00c\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\xb1\xfa\xb2\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xe5>\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00a\x00r\x00q\x00u\x00e\x00t\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\x80\xbd\xb3\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01A"\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00a\x00r\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00s\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01Q2\xb4\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xa3\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00i\x00c\x00k\x00l\x00e\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01<\x80\xb4\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xf3\x8c\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x90\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00y\x00t\x00a\x00b\x00l\x00e\x00s\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00h\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe5\xe4{\xfe\x8ah\xd7\x01\x9a\xe8\xd1\xe6\x18\xb0\xd7\x01\xc9\xfa\xb9\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xc9\xfa\xb9\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x00a\x00s\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\x9ao\xba\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xe7\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x00p\x00s\x00s\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01z\x0b\xbb\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x83\xfa\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x00q\x00l\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01R\x80\xbb\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xaa\xea\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x00t\x00a\x00t\x00a\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00x\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\xeb\xf0m\x8ah\xd7\x01\x80\x8cb\xc3\xd20\xd7\x01\x9f\x1d\x84\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00_\x00i\x00n\x00i\x00t\x00_\x00_\x00.\x00p\x00y\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00I_z\xfe\x8ah\xd7\x01\x9e\x0f\xd2\xe6\x18\xb0\xd7\x01\xdd\xff\x8d\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\xdd\xff\x8d\xff\x8ah\xd7\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00_\x00_\x00P\x00Y\x00C\x00A\x00~\x001\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00_\x00_\x00p\x00y\x00c\x00a\x00c\x00h\x00e\x00_\x00_\x00 0])\n    >>> mask_zero_div_zero(x, y, result)\n    array([ inf,  nan, -inf])\n    r\x01\x00\x00\x00\xda\x06ignore)\x01Z\x07invalidr\n\x00\x00\x00Fr\x0b\x00\x00\x00)\x0c\xda\nisinstancer\x0e\x00\x00\x00Z\x07ndarrayr\x04\x00\x00\x00r\x0f\x00\x00\x00\xda\x04boolr\x10\x00\x00\x00Z\x07signbitZ\x08errstater\x12\x00\x00\x00r\x13\x00\x00\x00\xda\x03inf)\tr\x15\x00\x00\x00r\x16\x00\x00\x00r\x14\x00\x00\x00Z\x05zmaskZ\tzneg_maskZ\tzpos_maskZ\x08nan_maskZ\x0bneginf_maskZ\x0bposinf_maskr\x18\x00\x00\x00r\x18\x00\x00\x00r\x19\x00\x00\x00\xda\x12mask_zero_div_zeroI\x00\x00\x00s(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1c\x0c\x02\x04\x02\x08\x01\n\x02\x08\x02\n\x02\x04\x02\x08\x03\x0e\x01\n\x02\x0c\x01\x0e\x01\x18\x01"\x02\x18\x02\x0e\x02\n\x01\n\x01\x0c\x02r\x1f\x00\x00\x00c\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\xb2\x00\x00\x00|\x00t\x00k\x08r*t\x01|\x01|\x02|\x03d\x01\x19\x00\x83\x03t\x02|\x03d\x02\x19\x00|\x01|\x02\x83\x03f\x02}\x03n\x84|\x00t\x03k\x08rTt\x01|\x02|\x01|\x03d\x01\x19\x00\x83\x03t\x02|\x03d\x02\x19\x00|\x02|\x01\x83\x03f\x02}\x03nZ|\x00t\x04j\x05k\x08rlt\x01|\x01|\x02|\x03\x83\x03}\x03nB|\x00t\x06k\x08r\x82t\x01|\x02|\x01|\x03\x83\x03}\x03n,|\x00t\x04j\x07k\x08r\x9at\x02|\x03|\x01|\x02\x83\x03}\x03n\x14|\x00t\x08k\x08r\xaet\x02|\x03|\x02|\x01\x83\x03}\x03|\x03S\x00)\x03a\x05\x02\x00\x00\n    Call fill_zeros with the appropriate fill value depending on the operation,\n    with special logic for divmod and rdivmod.\n\n    Parameters\n    ----------\n    op : function (operator.add, operator.div, ...)\n    left : object (np.ndarray for non-reversed ops)\n    right : object (np.ndarray for reversed ops)\n    result : ndarray\n\n    Returns\n    -------\n    result : np.ndarray\n\n    Notes\n    -----\n    For divmod and rdivmod, the `result` parameter and returned `result`\n    is a 2-tuple of ndarray objects.\n    r\x01\x00\x00\x00\xe9\x01\x00\x00\x00)\t\xda\x06divmodr\x1f\x00\x00\x00r\x1a\x00\x00\x00r\x05\x00\x00\x00\xda\x08operator\xda\x08floordivr\x06\x00\x00\x00\xda\x03modr\x07\x00\x00\x00)\x04\xda\x02op\xda\x04left\xda\x05rightr\x14\x00\x00\x00r\x18\x00\x00\x00r\x18\x00\x00\x00r\x19\x00\x00\x00\xda\x13dispatch_fill_zeros\x88\x00\x00\x00s"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x15\x08\x02\x0e\x01\x0e\xfe\x06\x04\x08\x02\x0e\x01\x0e\xfe\x06\x04\n\x03\x0e\x01\x08\x03\x0e\x01\n\x01\x0e\x01\x08\x01\x0c\x01r(\x00\x00\x00)\x0f\xda\x07__doc__r"\x00\x00\x00Z\x05numpyr\x0e\x00\x00\x00Z\x19pandas.core.dtypes.commonr\x02\x00\x00\x00r\x03\x00\x00\x00r\x04\x00\x00\x00Z\x19pandas.core.ops.roperatorr\x05\x00\x00\x00r\x06\x00\x00\x00r\x07\x00\x00\x00r\x1a\x00\x00\x00r\x1f\x00\x00\x00r(\x00\x00\x00r\x18\x00\x00\x00r\x18\x00\x00\x00r\x18\x00\x00\x00r\x19\x00\x00\x00\xda\x08<module>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x04\x17\x08\x02\x08\x02\x14\x02\x14\x03\x08(\x08?\x01\x00\x00f\x01|\x03\x00\x00'
```

Note above too that there is a pattern where you get \x00p\x00y\x00c for example, if you remove the \x00's you end up with .pycache strings and references to pyp packages etc.

So for the tagno 36012 I'm extracting the first 4 bytes and unpacking them as a float, which works fine. The problem I'm having is when trying the same query on a different tagno 36964 that has a data type of integer my python kernel dies. I am able to do this:

```
query = "SELECT value FROM phd_data where tagno = '36964' \
        and start_timestamp = 'NOW-::1'"
cursor.execute(query)
```

but as soon as I try to fetch rows from the cursor the kernel thinks and dies. I know there is data on this tag as I have another program that uses a different interface. I am able to query tags with Float and Unicode types, but not Integers. I can SELECT other columns like Tagname, Tagno, Timestamp from this Tagno, but just not Value.

My first question is whether there's anything wrong with my connection approach?

Secondly - why am I getting a long byte string when only the first 4 bytes are the value itself?

Thirdly - why would Integer data types fail when Float types don't?

Lastly - is there maybe a way I can Select only the first 4 bytes from PHD_DATA.VALUE maybe?

Comment: That string you posted is a Unicode string.  The ODBC connector should have realized that and returned it as a string.  Are you saying that `value` column has different data types in different rows?  That violates the SQL standard, and that may be why ODBC can't handle it.  You may end up converting them all by hand.

Comment: Hi Tim, the string was an excerpt from a longer byte string. The Value column outputs a byte string for all tags. I'll edit my post and include the entire string. However like I mentioned the byte string has some unicode characters that mention pycache and pyp etc.

Comment: Then value must be a "blob" type -- defined as 4096 bytes of undifferentiated data.  That means you'll need to decode it every time.  Is there a way for you to know what the datatype is?

Comment: Yes the manuals tell me that column is of variant type, and certain tags carry different data types as mentioned. It's only when I try to call tags of integer type that the kernel dies. No errors, just hangs and dies

Comment: What, exactly, happens when you try to pull an integer value?   You said "the kernel dies", but surely you don't mean the entire computer crashes.

Comment: no my Jupyter notebook shows the kernel is busy for 5s or so and then it gives me a red "Dead Kernel" message and the kernel restarts. No problems with Windows itself.

Comment: Is it possible there are many thousands of records with tagno=36964?  Remember, pandas will try to read every record into memory.

Comment: not in the time frame specified. other float-value tags return thousands of rows with no issues. in the time frame Now-::1 (within the last minute) i would expect about 3 or 4 rows. this is confirmed by a separate program that successfully pulls these tags. FWIW I appreciate your comments to help me debug Tim.

Comment: is there a way I can "debug" the pyodbc connection?? It seems like the connection isn't reading the value correctly, even for float-value tags where my workaround of taking the first 4 bytes seems to work.

Comment: Well, you have source for `pyodbc`, but that calls into a C library to do the real work.